# Headings for extended characters?

Tags: xetex, glossaries

How can I make a glossary headings for my extended characters?  I need them to be groups such as Š and '.  I do not want "default"!  Here's my xelatex MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy={glsnumbers=false},acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}  

\newglossaryentry{'oyx}{name='oyx,description={[conj] too, also},symbol={אױך}}
\newglossaryentry{frag}{name=frag,description={[v.t] to ask},symbol={פֿראַג}}
\newglossaryentry{šabes}{name=šabes,description={[n.f] Sabbath, Saturday},symbol={שאַבעס}}

\glsaddall

\glossarystyle{mcolindexgroup}
\printglossaries

blah blah

\end{document}
```

(I'm not actually writing in Yiddish or Hebrew.)

Comment: You need to tell `xindy` what language you are using otherwise it will use the English letter groups. (Also make sure you are using the latest version of `glossaries` as there were some issues with letter groups for non-English languages in earlier versions.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Care to expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `xindy` what language you are using. If you use `makeglossaries` and you don't specify the `xindy` language in your `.tex` file, `makeglossaries` will assume `english`. I don't know of any language module provided by `xindy` that recognises `'` as a letter group. There are some, such as `czech`, that recognize `š` as a letter group. For example:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy={glsnumbers=false,language=czech,codepage=utf8},acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{'oyx}{name='oyx,description={[conj] too, also},symbol={אױך}}
\newglossaryentry{frag}{name=frag,description={[v.t] to ask},symbol={פֿראַג}}
\newglossaryentry{šabes}{name=šabes,description={[n.f] Sabbath, Saturday},symbol={שאַבעס}}

\begin{document}  

\glsaddall

\setglossarystyle{mcolindexgroup}
\printglossaries

blah blah

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting glossary]

This deals with `šabes` but puts `'oyx` in the `O` letter group. If you need a separate group for `'` you'll probably have to define your own `xindy` alphabet. This is beyond my `xindy` knowledge, but there's a Perl script called [`make-rules`](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/make-rules.html) that is used for this.